# How to fix error 'not found husky-run' when committing new code?

Tags: git, husky

When committing on a project that uses Husky, I get an error that says `not found husky-run`

I checked the `package.json` and it has husky as a dependency, and I can see the pre-commit hook configuration for Husky in the `package.json`. So I don't know what to do to fix this. Additionally, other members on my team can commit and husky works for them.

I also tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` and then committing again, but still, I get the same error.

Anyone else have ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I got this after running `yarn install` inside a unix-based Docker container and then committing on Windows. Windows was unable to run the file, even thought it existed.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To fix this there are two methods, depending on which version of Husky you are already on.

If you're using Husky v4 or lower, do the following:

```sh
rm -rf .git/hooks
npm install
```

For Husky v7 or greater, do the following:

```sh
# For NPM
 npm install husky@7 --save-dev \
      && npx husky-init \
      && npm exec -- github:typicode/husky-4-to-7 --remove-v4-config

# For Yarn
 yarn add husky@7 --dev \
  && npx husky-init \
  && npm exec -- github:typicode/husky-4-to-7 --remove-v4-config
# or
 yarn add husky@7 --dev \
  && yarn dlx husky-init --yarn2 \
  && npm exec -- github:typicode/husky-4-to-7 --remove-v4-config
```

At this point you should be able to commit and have your hooks working again.

If anything goes wrong, please read the [documentation for migration from 4 to 7](https://github.com/typicode/husky-4-to-7).

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, `npm install` step wasn't required. Using yarn here

Comment: @dspacejs actually this solution worked for yarn too. Try to first delete your node_modules manually then reinstall.

Comment: I'm always wary of solution with command line starting by `rm -rf`. Nuking a whole directory sound a bit much, especially when there is a migration script.

Comment: this didn't work for me, git hooks directory was not recreated

Comment: OK so this might have worked just fine for husky version 4 or older, but if you've upgraded to husky 6 then you need to follow the answer from Uladz Kha below.

Comment: this did it for me

Comment: Thankyou - worked a treat - FYI use `rm -Recurse -Force .git/hooks` for Powershell

Answer (score 18):

To fix this in husky version 6 run:

```
yarn husky install
```

Answer (score 10):

Do not delete `.get/hooks` hooks won't work.
According [migrating manual from 4 to 6 version](https://github.com/typicode/husky-4-to-6) :

For npm usage execute

```
 npm install husky@6 --save-dev \
      && npx husky-init \
      && npm exec -- github:typicode/husky-4-to-6 --remove-v4-config
```

For yarn usage:

```
 yarn add husky@6 --dev \
  && npx husky-init \
  && npm exec -- github:typicode/husky-4-to-6 --remove-v4-config
```

and

```
yarn add husky@6 --dev \
  && yarn dlx husky-init --yarn2 \
  && npm exec -- github:typicode/husky-4-to-6 --remove-v4-config
```

If any errors while the process you can simply revert changes by executing:

```
rm -rf .husky && git config --unset core.hooksPath
```

Explanation what's going on:

husky init sets up Git hooks and updates your `package.json` scripts (you may want to commit your changes to `package.json` before running husky init).

`husky-4-to-6` creates hooks based on your husky v4 config. If `--remove-v4-config` is passed, previous config will be deleted (recommended).

Comment: FYI People, you need **npm version 7** to run the last script in this thing.

Comment: I concur, needed npm version 7 to get this to work. After I ran the scripts, I reverted to npm 6 and nodejs 12 and things are still functioning correctly for me. Also this section of their help docs can help you update your scripts to work with husky@6: https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=migrate-from-v4-to-v6

Comment: i have npm 6 and node 10 beause of project limitations. probably thats why it broke for me...

Comment: please try to `yarn husky install` for npm 6

Comment: ALSO make sure you are on `git` version 2.9 or above ✅ (I was not and Husky 6 was not working after going through the migration cli steps). Found this little detail tucked in the fine print of the Husky migration docs and this resolved it.

Answer (score 8):

I simply had to add a prepare script to my `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "prepare": "husky install",
  ...
}
```

Then run `yarn install` or `npm install` and husky will be initialized. This will make sure people who check out your repo will also be able to run husky.

Answer (score 5):

just a "yarn install" solved this for me

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

add a file ~/.huskyrc if you don't have one already

- touch ~/.huskyrc
- open ~/.huskyrc
- paste the following:

```
# ~/.huskyrc
# This loads nvm.sh and sets the correct PATH before running hook
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Comment: This one worked for me with `husky@4` Ty

Answer (score 2):

I occur this problem because the `.git` folder is at a different level from the `package.json` file, I resolved it by referencing this document:

https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory

Just like this:

```
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "cd .. && husky install front/.husky"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just this 'yarn add husky@6 --dev' inside your terminal

Answer (score 0):

If it may help anyone experiencing this issue and using `yarn`, uninstalling and reinstalling the `husky` package has fixed it in my case.

(Please check if you would need `-W` [flag](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/#toc-yarn-add-ignore-workspace-root-check-w) else remove it from the commands)

**uninstall:**

```
 yarn remove husky -W
```

**install:**

```
 yarn add husky@^4.2.5 -W //to install a specific version
 
 (or)
 
 yarn add husky -W //to install the latest version
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ayman Bakri's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72165198/8706387), and based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/phdesign/78ee9f055ee9762cb5c324249b040648), if you are using a git frontend like [Fork](https://git-fork.com/) together with [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) and you are getting errors like `npx: command not found`, then you have to source asdf.sh in your ~/.huskyrc as follows:

```
source /usr/local/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
```

if you installed asdf via a package manager like homebrew, or:

```
source ~/.asdf/asdf.sh
```

if you installed asdf using [the instructions](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#official-download). You must source the bash compatible script `asdf.sh` even if your default shell is Fish.

Answer (score 0):

My `NODE_ENV` was set to `production`. Unsetting it, then rerunning `npm i` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

##### If you think you have all well configured in your project and still having this issue, ensure you also install yarn globally:

```
npm install --global yarn
```

---

> Some terminals, consoles or other external tools like GitHub desktop
> are no using the local yarn, but the global.