# Source control and terminal conflict (version.json typechange)

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code, githooks, git-husky

I encountered an error when attempting to commit via the VSCode source control. The OUTPUT tab revealed that Git was searching for `version.json` (which is a symlink) with the incorrect path. After some research, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246587/how-to-fix-error-not-found-husky-run-when-committing-new-code). However, now I have `version.json` appearing in my diff, and when I try to open it, I receive the following message:

```
The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unable to read file 'c:/Users.../src/version.json (Unkown (FileSystemError): Error:EINVAL: invalid argument, readlink 'c:/Users.../src/version.json)''
```

Before reinstalling Husky, my Git was searching the file for the wrong path. When I undo the changes via source control, they start to appear in my git terminal (I'm running Ubuntu WSL).

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        typechange: src/version.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I attempted to reclone the project on the same path and encountered the same issue after running `yarn` There was a diff with an inaccessible file and a bug. Even when I used the `checkout` command or `stash`, the problematic file change reappeared in the source control.

Any ideias?

Edit:

Since a comment suggested it's a problem with hook configuration I'm adding it's config here to add more context, those are my `package.json` lines for the hook (rusky is running on version 4):

```json
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "pre-push": "CI=true yarn test"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ],
    "src/**/*.{css,js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Just found out this version.json is a symlink

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: That sounds like a badly configured hook (or what the hook is calling, let's say), not really a `git` problem.

Comment: I've added the hook config on the question

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution to the issue by recloning the repo. This time, instead of using the `Clone with SSH` option as paste address through my WSL terminal, I chose the `Visual Studio Code (SSH)` option.

This change appears to have enabled the Visual Studio Code's source control to properly handle the symlink, thereby resolving the confusion that existed between wsl/git/terminal and vscode/git/source control.